# I/O performance in mzscheme

Tags: performance, io, scheme, tcl, racket

Being a Linux administrator, I used to write my scripts in Bash, TCL and, less often, in Perl. Just out of curiosity, I tried to write something in mzscheme, but what I found out was that the performance was so much worse. I cut the script to simply reading a 500MB log file:

```
#lang scheme
(require rnrs/programs-6)
(call-with-input-file (vector-ref (current-command-line-arguments) 0)
    (lambda (in)
            (let loop ((line (read-line in)))
                    (unless (eof-object? line)
                            (loop (read-line in))))))
```

This simple process takes about 40 seconds. The same script, adapted for Guile, executes in 10 seconds. TCL version runs for 5 seconds. Chicken Scheme takes only 3.8 seconds, ten time less than MZScheme:

```
#!/usr/bin/csi -script
(call-with-input-file (list-ref (command-line-arguments) 0)
    (lambda (in)
            (let loop ((line (read-line in)))
                    (if (not (eof-object? line))
                            (loop (read-line in))))))
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there any recommendations on writing faster MZScheme programs?

Some more tests:

```
minaev@minaev:~/1$ time ./t.tcl blog.log

real    0m8.907s
user    0m8.417s
sys     0m0.468s
Mon Oct 31 13:15:19 MSK 2011
minaev@minaev:~/1$ time ./t.scm blog.log # Chicken 4.2.0

real    0m7.678s
user    0m6.896s
sys     0m0.580s
Mon Oct 31 13:15:29 MSK 2011
minaev@minaev:~/1$ time /usr/bin/mzscheme t.ss blog.log # mzscheme 4.2.1

real    0m44.047s
user    0m41.803s
sys     0m0.948s
Mon Oct 31 13:17:03 MSK 2011
minaev@minaev:~/1$ time racket t.ss blog.log  # racket 5.1.3

real    0m25.287s
user    0m23.189s
sys     0m0.828s
Mon Oct 31 13:17:39 MSK 2011
minaev@minaev:~/1$ raco make t.ss
Mon Oct 31 13:17:47 MSK 2011
minaev@minaev:~/1$ time racket t.ss blog.log  # racket 5.1.3 byte-compiled

real    0m23.237s
user    0m22.469s
sys     0m0.688s
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the exact Tcl script you were using to compare? I ask as a Tcl hacker…

Comment: I'm afraid, the code will be mangled in the comment, but it's so trivial, that it shouldn't be a problem :)
     proc parse {log} {
        set f [open $log]
        while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
        }
     }
     parse [lindex $argv 0]

Comment: I am trying to understand the problem a little better, but I am unfamiliar with TCL. I looked up `gets` in the TCL manual in order to see whether the strings are UTF8-strings or normal byte-strings. It didn't say - do you happen to know whether TCL uses utf8-strings in your example?

Comment: @soegaard: It will be doing because I can see that he didn't turn it off. (It turns out to be the right thing to do for almost everything except stupid benchmarks…)

Comment: @soegaard: Yes, the system locale is UTF-8, so the input channel is configured to read UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been substantially improved in the development version of Racket.  See the commit [here](https://github.com/plt/racket/commit/9896cb68) and the message from Racket maintainer Matthew Flatt [here](http://lists.racket-lang.org/dev/archive/2011-November/008271.html).  It should now be only about 50% slower than Chicken. The remaining slowdown is primarily due to the additional features Racket provides, such as events, line-counting, unicode encoding, and others.

Comment: So, the many years old bug gets fixed as soon as I ask about it? I feel lucky (c) :) Thank you very much, it's a relief. Fifty percent seems to be an acceptable price.

Answer (score 1):

I tried repeating your results, and I got about 3.4s for Chicken 4.5.0 and about 10s for various versions of mzscheme/racket. (I tried mzscheme from PLT Scheme 4.2 and racket from both Racket 5.1.1 and the development tree, all compiled in 64-bit mode.)

What version of mzscheme are you using? What platform?

Are your timings repeatable? (I wonder about block cache effects.)

Comment: My hardware/software is quite similar to yours. mzscheme was installed from Ubuntu 10.04 repositories, it's v4.2.1 [3m], "x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15".

Comment: And yes, the results are reproducible on various hardware/software with, probably, less striking, but still impressive gap.

Comment: Bear in mind that `read-line` gives you a string, which means that you pay some cpu cycles for the conversion.  You could use `read-bytes-line` for raw `char*`-like strings.

Comment: Aha... I thought there must be some overhead from input processing, but I left it as it is because I wanted the semantics to be consistent in various implementations: Chicken, Racket or TCL. Besides, I wanted to process the text file, I didn't want to just slurp it. Sometimes I might want to do something with the strings, which might contain Cyrillic characters.
BTW, the variant with read-bytes-line wasn't any faster :(

Comment: @minaev: Can you wrap the last expression in your mzscheme/racket version with `time` and report what it prints? I'm curious about cpu vs gc time.

Comment: @minaev: BTW, on my machine using a dynamically linked version of racket caused a 20% performance hit (about 10s to about 12s).

Comment: @RyanCulpepper: The last expression being `call-with-input-file`? Here it is: cpu time: 24589 real time: 25398 gc time: 372